# How to fix the error react hook cannot be called inside a callback function using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to display the company name and owner name when the item is shared.

in doing so i get the error

"react hook cannot be used in callback function.React hooks must be called in a react functional component or a custom react hook function"

below is my code,

```
function Parent () {
    const ownedItems = [{//someobject}];
    const sharedItems = [{//someobject}];

    const getCurrentItems() {
        return  ownedItems.concat(sharedItems);
    }

    return(
        <Wrapper>
            {getCurrentItems.length > 0 &&
                (
                    <>
                        <FirstWrapper>
                            //some other divs
                        </FirstWrapper>
                        <SecondWrapper>
                            {
                                someprops.map((
                                    index
                                ) => {
                                    const item  = getCurrentItems()[index];
                                    const isSharedItem =
                                        item.cognitoId !== cognitoId;
                                    if (isSharedItem) {
                                        const { data: company } =    useGetCompanyByItemId(item.id); //i get error here

                                    }

                                    return (
                                        <Card>
                                            <Header>
                                                some content
                                            </Header>
                                            <Footer>
                                                {isSharedItem &&
                                                    <div>
                                                        <span>company</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                 }
                                             </Footer>
                                         </Card>
                                     );
                                 });
                             </SecondWrapper>
                         
                         </Wrapper>
                     );
                 }
```

I am not sure how to get data from useGetCompanyByItemId such that i can use it rendering the span in Footer.

could someone help me with this. I am new to using hooks. thanks.

Comment: "React hooks must be called in a react functional component" - create a new component with all that logic that you have in the callback function for map.

Comment: thanks could you please provide the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is surprisingly similar/same to another one. Colleagues may be? I just answered there:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63153237/2931410

I can see two ways of refactoring here:

**Option 1: If you dont have control over the custom hook to modify**

Extract the iteration into a component:

```
const Company = ({itemId, isSharedItem}) => {
   const company = useGetCompanyByItemId(itemId);
   return (<>
      {isSharedItem && 
          (<div>
             <span>{company}</span>
           </div>)
      }
      </>);
}
```

Use the above component while you iterate.

**Option 2: If you have control over the custom  hook:**
I would recommend to refactor custom hook to return a method than object. Sample usage:

`const {getCompanyByItemId} = useFetchCompany();`

.
.
.

anywhere in the code,
`getCompanyByItemId(itemId)`

***Obvious advantage with above option:***

- Readable and extendable and use it anywhere and even pass around
- You don't have to worry about refactoring and code splitting just not to break hook rules(do so if it makes sense ofcourse).

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are JavaScript functions, but you need to follow two rules when using them.

**Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

**Only Call Hooks from React Functions**
Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

✅ Call Hooks from React function components.

✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks

More Info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I'm just checking out react and functional components seem to be a complete nightmare. If I can't change say, the an items "color" property in a condition, loop or callback, when what's the alternative? Everything modern has migrated to them, but I find them needlessly more complicated than class based components were.